# Can capital loss in traditional IRA and Roth IRA be used to offset taxable income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-ira, capital-loss

For traditional IRA and Roth IRA, can capital loss be used to offset taxable income for tax purpose?

If not, when withdrawing from traditional IRA and Roth IRA, can the capital loss now be used to offset taxable income?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited in response to JoeTaxpayer's comment and OP Tim's additional question.

To add to and clarify a little what littleadv has said, and to answer 
OP Tim's next question:

- As far as the IRS is concerned, you have **at most one** Individual
  Retirement Account of each type (Traditional, Roth) though the money
  in each IRA can be invested with as many different custodians
  (brokerages, banks, etc.) and different investments as you like.
  Thus, the maximum $5000 ($6000 for older folks) that you can contribute
  each year can be split up and invested any which way you like, and when in later
  years you take a Required Minimum Distribution (RMD) from a Traditional
  IRA, you can get the money by selling just one of the investments,
  or from several investments; all that the IRS cares is that
  the total amount that is distributed to you is at least as large as the RMD.
  An important corollary is that

  > **the balance in your IRA is the
  >   sum total of the value of all the investments that various custodians are holding
  >   for you in IRA accounts.**
- There is no loss in an IRA until *every penny* has been
  withdrawn from *every investment* in your IRA and 
  distributed to you, thus making your IRA
  balance zero.  As long as you have a positive balance,
  there is no loss: everything has to come out.
- After the *last distribution* from your
  Roth IRA (the one that empties your *entire*
  Roth IRA, no matter where it is invested and reduces
  your Roth IRA balance (see definition  above) to zero),
  total up *all* the amounts that you have received as 
  distributions from your Roth IRA. If this is less 
  than the total amount of money you contributed to your Roth IRA 
  (this includes rollovers from a Traditional IRA or Roth 401k 
  etc., but **not** the earnings within the Roth IRA
  that you re-invested inside the Roth IRA), you have
  a loss that can be deducted on Schedule A as a Miscellaneous
  Deduction subject to the 2% AGI limit. This 2% is **not a cap**
  (in the sense that no more than 2% of your AGI can be deducted
  in this category)  but rather a **threshold:** you can only
  deduct whatever part of
  your *total* Miscellaneous Deductions **exceeds**  2% of your AGI.
  Not many people have Miscellaneous Deductions whose total exceeds
  2% of their AGI, and so they end up not being able to deduct
  anything in this category.
- If you ever made *nondeductible* contributions to your 
  Traditional IRA because you were ineligible to make a 
  deductible contribution (income too high, pension plan 
  coverage at work etc), then the sum of all these
  contributions is your *basis* in your 
  Traditional IRA. Note that **your deductible contributions,
  if any, are not part of the basis.**  The above rules apply to 
  your basis in your Traditional IRA
  as well.  After the last distribution from your Traditional
  IRA (the one that empties 
  all your Traditional IRA accounts and reduces your
  Traditional IRA balance to zero), total up all the
  distributions that you received (don't forget to
  include the nontaxable part of each distribution
  that represents a return of the basis). If the sum
  total is less than your basis, you have a loss
  that can be deducted on Schedule A as a Miscellaneous 
  Deduction subject to the 2% AGI threshold.
- You can only deposit cash into an IRA and take a
  distribution in
  cash from an IRA. Now, as JoeTaxpayer points out,
  if your IRA owns stock,
  you can take a distribution by having the 
  shares transferred from your IRA account in your brokerage
  to your personal account in the brokerage.  However, the
  **amount of the distribution**, as reported by the brokerage
  to the IRS, is the **value of the shares
  transferred as of the time of the transfer,** (more generally 
  the fair market value of the property that is transferred out of
  the IRA) and this is the amount you report on your income 
  tax return. Any capital gain or loss on those
  shares remains inside the IRA because your basis (in
  your personal account) in the 
  shares that came out of the IRA is the amount of the
  distribution.  If you sell these shares at a later date,
  you will have a (taxable) gain or loss depending on whether
  you sold the shares for more or less than your basis.
  In effect, the share transfer transaction is as if you
  sold the shares in the IRA, took the proceeds as a
  cash distribution and immediately bought the same shares
  in your personal account, but you saved the transaction
  fees for the sale and the purchase and avoided paying the 
  difference between the buying and selling price of the
  shares as well as any changes in these in the microseconds
  that would have elapsed between the execution of
  the sell-shares-in-Tim's-IRA-account, distribute-cash-to-Tim,
  and buy-shares-in-Tim's-personal account transactions.  Of course, your broker will likely
  charge a fee for transferring ownership of the shares from
  your IRA to you.  But the important point is that
  **any capital
  gain or loss within the IRA cannot be used to offset a gain or loss in
  your taxable accounts.**  What happens inside the IRA stays
  inside the IRA.

Comment: One correction - withdrawals can be made "in-kind." You are correct that new deposits are cash only, but one can take a withdrawal by simply transferring assets from the IRA to a non-sheltered account. This goes to the issue of those who are so afraid of RMDs. Tax is due on the value of the assets transferred, but the asset does not to be sold. (if you decide to edit your response, I'll kill this comment)

Comment: Thanks! In your first part, (1) "If the total amount of money that you withdraw from your Roth IRA is less than the total amount of money you contributed to your Roth IRA ...", is this withdrawal one time thing? How is this withdrawal empty the entire Roth IRA? (2) "... a threshold: you can only deduct whatever part of your total Miscellaneous Deductions exceeds 2% of your AGI." Does it mean that the amount that I can deduct is the "total Miscellaneous Deductions" minus 2% of the AGI?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! (1) "you can only deduct whatever part of your total Miscellaneous Deductions exceeds 2% of your AGI", do you mean what I you can deduct is equal to "my total miscellaneous deductions" minus "2% of my AGI"? (2) Suppose I have a huge capital loss in my Roth IRA, and I basically don't have much other income. If the capital loss has some left after offsetting income, can the left be carried over to the next years, although my AGI will change in the next years (and therefore the left capital loss this year may not surpass 2% of my AGI in the next years)?

Comment: "Suppose I have a huge capital loss in my Roth IRA, and I basically don't have much other income. If the capital loss has some left after offsetting income, can the left be carried over to the next year.."  Tim, what part of the following sentence, which I specifically set in bold font in my answer, do you not understand? **any capital gain or loss within the IRA cannot be used to offset a gain or loss in your taxable accounts**?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thanks! I should have asked "If the capital loss has some left after it is deducted on Schedule A as a Miscellaneous Deduction subject to the 2% AGI threshold, can the left-over be carried to the next years?

Comment: Tim: In simplest terms **On the tax return for the year in which your Roth IRA balance becomes zero, if you have a loss -- total distributions less than total contributions --, you MIGHT be able to deduct it (or some part of it) on Schedule A because of the 2% AGI threshold. Whatever falls below the threshold is lost forever. Also, it is a use it or lose it deal. THERE IS NO UNUSED PART TO BE CARRIED OVER TO FUTURE YEARS, NOT THE PART THAT WENT BELOW THE THRESHOLD NOR ANY PART THAT YOU "SAVE" FOR USE IN FUTURE YEARS.  IT IS GONE.** Just suck it up and grin to hide your pain.

Comment: Thanks! In the part 4 of your reply, you discuss the case for traditional IRA when there are both deductible and non-deductible contributions and the account is being emptied.  I wonder how the loss is computed in such case?

Comment: Two examples. In example 2 of http://www.fool.com/personal-finance/taxes/2004/08/20/deduct-ira-losses-in-some-cases.aspx, the loss is calculated as the difference between total distributions and basis. In the example near the end of http://www.easyretirementknowhow.com/articlecategories/QualifiedPlans/sya110607ira-deductingIRAlossesPIC.htm, the loss is the distributions minus basis minus deductible (i.e. tax-deferred) contribution. I wonder which example is correct?

Comment: Both examples are correct. Once again, you seem not to be paying attention to what the examples are trying to explain to you, and failing to understand the examples.

Comment: I now see the two examples are consistent with each other. But the final balance consists of parts from both the deductible and nondeducitble contributions. Isn't the loss supposed to be calculated for nondeductible contribution only? I posted my confusion in a new post http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15450/calculate-loss-in-traditional-ira-for-deduction

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer With regard to distributions in-kind rather than in cash, did you notice a [recent response](http://groups.google.com/group/misc.taxes.moderated/browse_thread/thread/c64c37473ffa5ded/a5a8e5ac3a8be745#a5a8e5ac3a8be745) in misc.taxes.moderated which said "Six types of distributions are specifically allowed to be in-kind.  RMDs are not among them."?

Comment: Indeed. So far, the regulars agree with me. I added an answer to Stussy pointing out both my experience doing exactly this as well as the Schwab form allowing the transaction. Until I see an IRS authored document, I am going with my experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

If you withdraw everything from all your Roth IRA's and end up with less than the total basis - you can deduct the difference on your schedule A (at the time of the last withdrawal) as an itemized deduction (as misc. deductions with 2% AGI cap).

Regular IRA's are pre-tax, you cannot deduct anything from them.

Comment: THanks! Since withdrawing from  traditional IRA is subject to tax, I wonder if withdrewing will make the capital loss in traditional IRA be able to offset taxable income?

Comment: Tim - let's be clear - The traditional IRA is typically pretax money. There's no such thing as the ability to recognize the capital loss in that situation. For the Roth, or post-tax money in the Traditional IRA, the 2% floor kicks in.